# UiAutomator - UiDevice can't findObject by selector (package name and resource ID)

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I'm unable to find an element (`UiObject2`) using UiAutomator within my androidTest. I obtained UiDevice instance and try to find the object with this:

```
MY_UI_DEVICE.findObject(By.res(CURRENT_PACKAGE, id));
```

`CURRENT_PACKAGE` is the package of my app `MY_UI_DEVICE.getCurrentPackageName()`. I tried also with this one:

```
MY_UI_DEVICE.wait(Until.findObject(By.res(CURRENT_PACKAGE, id)), 10000);
```

I can see the app is waiting for 10 seconds on the right screen (where the desired object persists), but after timeout it fails to find it and test fails. It always fails on emulator (API 23), but rarely works good on a real device (API 25).

When I debug the code I could see that manually I could obtain the right element by calling sequence of `getChild(index)` methods on `AccessibilityNodeInfo` but in the runtime it still fails even the app is waiting on the right screen where I expect the specific element.

I was playing with different UiDevice's functions, but none of the helped and I'm out of ideas, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were 2 issues with my tests:

1. The first problem was in getting / initialising `UiDevice` instance in static block (as a static field in util class). I moved it into `@Before`and it helped to resolve the issue partially.
2. Another problem was occurring while searching for an element using a package name obtained from the `UiDevice`. I replaced getting package with `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageName();` as it's done in [google samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/blob/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/blueprint/ui/uiautomator/UiAutomatorTest.java).

Comment: faced same problem, fixed issue by using package name returned by InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageName()

Answer (score 1):

Try use UiSelector methods. That worked for me much better than By selectors

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Test method is throwing the `UiObjectNotFoundException`. I had this issue with UiObject2 as well until I started forcing the error throw

```
@Test
public void clockTest() throws UiObjectNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    mDevice.click(1146,37); //click on clock top right corner
    Thread.sleep(1500);//wait 1.5 seconds for screen to load
    mDevice.click(1138,135);//clicks in shell
    Thread.sleep(1500);//wait 1.5s for screen to load

    UiObject2 dTSettingsButton = mDevice.findObject(By.text("Date & Time Settings"));
    //assertNotNull(dTSettingsButton);//find and assert the settings button
    dTSettingsButton.clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);//clicks the settings button

    UiObject2 timeFormatButton = mDevice.findObject(By.text("Select Time Format"));
    assertNotNull(timeFormatButton);//find and assert timeformat button
    timeFormatButton.clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);//click timeformat button

    UiObject2 twelveHourButton = mDevice.findObject(By.res("com.REDACTED.settings:id/first_btn"));
    assertNotNull(twelveHourButton);//find and assert twelvehour button
    twelveHourButton.clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);//click twelvehour button
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually the problem is that I can't find an object at all by calling `findObject` on `UiDevice` instance. How throwing `UiObjectNotFoundException` can help?

Comment: Have you used UiAutomator Viewer tool to inspect the screen and get the resource ID or other information that would allow you to use `UiObject` over `UiObject2`?

Comment: Yes, I did. The resource ID is correct. As I mentioned it works sometimes. For a real device it works almost always, but for emulator it doesn't. Besides, I think I found the problem. I had `UiDevice` initialization in static block in different class (kept as a static field). When I moved it to `@Before` method it works. Thanks for your comments tho.